# Comparing schemas on different server

Tags: db2

I have to compare a schema `X` which exists on 2 servers i.e. S1 and S2. Can anyone please help me out as to how I can compare all the tables in schema `X` that exist on `S1` and `S2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare table names run this query on both servers, exporting the data returned into a file then run a diff utility against the two files to find any differences.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM SYSIBM.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'X'
```

If you need to compare all the columns in all the tables use this query instead:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TYPE_NAME, COLUMN_SIZE, DECIMAL_DIGITS
FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = 'X'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```